# Nonprincipal prime ideals contain two relatively prime elements

Tags: commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and let $P$ be a nonprincipal prime ideal of $R[x]$. I'm having trouble seeing why $P$ must contain two elements with no common divisor.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Actually your problem is to show that *a non-principal prime ideal in a UFD contains two relatively prime elements* and this is easy enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in Pete L. Clark's [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

Since $R[x]$ is a UFD (this must be shown separately) the nonzero prime ideal $P$ contains a prime (hence irreducible) element $f_1$ (take nonzero $x\in P$ and factor into primes; since $P$ is prime, one of these must be in $P$). Since $P$ is nonprincipal there exists $f_2\in P\setminus (f_1)$. Now if $g$ is a common factor of $f_1$ and $f_2$ then in particular $g$ is a factor of $f_1$. Since $f_1$ is irreducible this implies that $g$ is a unit or associate to $f_1$. But if $g$ is associate to $f_1$ then the fact that $g$ divides $f_2$ means that $f_1$ divides $f_2$, contradiction. Hence $f_1$ and $f_2$ have no common factor.

Answer (score 2):

If $p \ne 0$ is a prime element in $R$, consider $(p, x) \subseteq R[x]$. (By the way, it is not true that every prime ideal in $R[x]$ is nonprincipal - for example $(x)$ is a principal prime ideal - but the maximal ideals are guaranteed to be nonprincipal).

Comment: I must confess that I had read this too quickly, and only answered a question that I gleaned from the title - i.e. what is a nonprincipal prime in $R[x]$. Since the OP has apparently solved the problem on his own though, I'll leave this for anyone who might find it useful. As for the problem with units: take your time! I agree that small fish are fun (and quick) to fry